# How to retrieve Graphics Card Information in UWP in C++

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

There seem to be several ways of doing it in Win32 environment, using interfaces such as ManagementObjectSearcher. However, I am unable to find a way to achieve it in UWP. There is nothing akin to Graphics Card Adapter in Device Interface Classes either.

I couldn't find any MSDN documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the list of supported Win32 APIs in UWP:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt644397.aspx

It contains the IDXGIFactory interface, which has the EnumAdapters method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bb174538.aspx

Comment: Indeed, I was able to use IDXGIFactory1::EnumAdapters1 to enumerate on the available adapters correctly. Thank you.